# Is there a way to generate a map of the existing tables and their relationships to each other?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, erd

Access has something like this where you view all the relationships between the existing tables, displayed as lines connecting them: keys, 1 to many, etc. I can't find anything in ss2008 - I'm very new to it on top of that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is called an Entity Relationship or ER diagram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

open up the database folder  for the database that you are interested in, click on `database diagram`, click on yes when a confirmation box pops up
right click on `database diagrams` and select new database diagram

Pick all the tables you want, click add and a diagram will be created

Now you can save the diagram, give it a useful name and it will be available next time you want to look at it

Comment: The tables show up without any lines. I picked one table I knew had it's PK as a FK in another table to test it. Does something have to be set up when creating those tables for the relationship lines to show? There are about 40-50 tables and it'd just help me visualize what's going on without having to query every table to see for myself. I can draw the lines in myself and am prompted with a bunch of "stuff", but I'm new on the job so I don't want to mess something up just yet. =)

Comment: I just verified that the `lines` show up. Are you sure you have fk constraints setup?

Comment: I didn't set up anything with the database. I got here and it is how it is. Maybe that's something they didn't set up if that's necessary for the lines to show up. I'll do some homework on how to check that. Thanks.

Comment: Just looking over things, it doesn't look like those constraints were set up, so I'll just have to deal with it for now. Thanks for the help, Menace.

Comment: Now is a good time to add those constraints yourself. You'll probably find you can't because there is dirty data